# The expression prints itself in unexpected order

Tags: scala

When I print a log information like this:

```
val idList = getIdList
log info s"\n\n-------idList: ${idList foreach println}"
```

It shows me:

```
1
2
3
4
5
-------idList: ()
```

That makes sense because `foreach` returns `Unit`. But why does it print the list of id first? `idList` is already evaluated in the previous line (if that's the cause)!

And how to make it print it in expected order - after `idList:`?

Comment: The println is a side effect of the expression ``idList foreach println``, the ${ .. } section is evaluated first, so the list is sent to println first

Comment: @Alex, did anyone explain in a way you understand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you're not evaluating the log string to read what you want, you evaluate it to:

```
\n\n    -------idList: ()
```

However, **the members of the list appear in the output stream as a side effect, due to the `println` call in the string interpolation.**

---

EDIT: *since clarification was requested by the OP,* what happens is that the **output comes from *two* sources**:

1. `${idList foreach println}` evaluates to `()`, since `println` **itself** doesn't return anything.
2. **However**, you can see the elements printed out, **because when the string interpolation is evaluated, `println` is being called**. And `println` prints all the elements into the output stream.

In other words:

```
//line with log.info() reached, starts evaluating string before method call
1 //println from foreach
2 //println from foreach
3 //println from foreach
4 //println from foreach
5 //println from foreach
//string argument log.info() evaluated from interpolation
-------idList: () //log info prints the resultant string
```

---

To solve your problem, **modify the expression in the interpolated string to actually return the correct string**, e.g.:

```
log info s"\n\n-------idList: ${idList.mkString("\n")}"
```

Comment: To print the string, the `idList foreach println` expression has to be evaluated first (which of course has no value). While evaluating println gets called for each element. Then the string can be printed.

Comment: @Alex : exactly what Kigyo (and I ;) ) said. Extended the answer with additional clarification, for posterity.

Comment: Better usage: `log info (1 to 5).mkString("\n--ids\n", ",", "\n")` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Interpolation works in a following way:

1. evaluate all arguments
2. substitute their results into resulting string

Answer (score 0):

println is a Unit function that prints to the standard output, you should use mkstring instead that returns a string

```
log info s"\n\n-------idList: ${idList.mkString("(", ", ", ")")}"
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @TheTerribleSwiftTomato , you need to give an expression that returns a value and has no other side-effect. So simply do it like this:

```
val idList = getIdList
log info s"\n\n-------idList: ${idList mkString " "}"
```

For example, this works for me:

```
val idList = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
println(s"\n\n-------idList: ${idList mkString " "}")
```

Output:

```
-------idList: 1 2 3 4 5
```